# database insert with "if else" rules through pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to do a mysql insert through pdo. the insert works fine, but i'm in need of some if else rules and cant wrap my head around it since pdo is unfamiliar to me.

Here's the insert code:

```
$qry = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT INTO statistics (page, who, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)');
$qry->execute(array($pdotitle, $name, $ip));
```

This does what it says correctly, but i need to make a rule that selects rows from the statistics and checks if a row with the users ip already exists.

something like this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['remote_addr']
$qry = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE page = :pdotitle);
$qry->execute(array($pdotitle)');
if (ip == '$ip') { /**do nothing**/ } else { /**do insert**/ }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Syntax highlighting already shows you what's wrong with your code ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably thought of this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['remote_addr']
$qry = $dbh->prepare(
    'SELECT * FROM statistics WHERE page = :pdotitle AND ip = :ip');
$qry->execute(array($pdotitle, $ip));
$row = $qry->fetch();
if (!is_null($row)) { /**do insert**/ }
```

What you should do is using SQL correctly though. Put a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `ip` column and you can do

```
// insert each ip only only and ignore the rest
$qry = $dbh->prepare(
    'INSERT IGNORE INTO statistics (page, who, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' 
);

// but maybe you really want to keep the table updated 
$qry = $dbh->prepare(
    'REPLACE INTO statistics (page, who, ip) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' 
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer's :)
I should have fiddled with it abit more before asking, but now it works as should :)